# Rename part of filename using regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, rename

I have a bunch of files where there is additional information in square brackets. I would like to rename them by removing that section.

For example:

```
filename [additional info 1].ext1
anotherfile [different info 2].ext2
```

Want to rename to:

```
filename.ext1
anotherfile.ext2
```

I tried playing with regex (and using the rename command) but without success. Does anybody know a way to have the rename command strip of only the part of " [....]" (including the leading space).

Comment: Please post the commands and regex you tried.

Comment: Are there just a few different extensions, or many tens/hundreds?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looping for each file and using sed for some simple regex matching:

```
for i in *.ext*; do 
    mv "$i" "$(sed 's/ \[[^]]*\]\././' <<<"$i")"
done
```

Tested with:

```
$ touch 'filename [additional info 1].ext1' 'filename [additional info 2].ext2'
$ for i in *.ext*; do mv -v "$i" "$(sed 's/ \[[^]]*\]\././' <<<"$i")"; done
renamed 'filename [additional info 1].ext1' -> 'filename.ext1'
renamed 'filename [additional info 2].ext2' -> 'filename.ext2'
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following:  
    `mv: ‘filename [additional info 1].ext1’ and ‘filename [additional info 1].ext1’ are the same file`                                                        
    `mv: ‘anotherfile [different info 2].ext2’ and ‘anotherfile [different info 2].ext2’ are the same file`

Comment: Right a typo. Edited. ; )